# Primefaces Lightbox: How to call hide()-method

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a lightbox with only one image. Yes, I know its not really inteded for that.

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox" widgetVar="light">
  <h:outputLink value="#{imageBean.getImageResourceLink(id)}" title="#{name}" onclick="light.hide();"/> 
   <h:graphicImage library="thumb_lib" name="#{id}" width="165"/>
  </h:outputLink>  
</p:lightBox>
```

Now I want the lightbox to be closed/hided when I click inside the opened lightbox.
This doesn't work as expected. Only when I click the lightbox navigation-arrows the lightbox hides. Good, hiding somehow works. But how can I hide it by just clicking inside the lightbox?

How can I achieve this?

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any "onclick" events inside the `p:lightBox`

So I guess you could use the help of jQuery...
The following should work just fine (add to your js file or script tag)

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".imagebox", "click", function (event) {
    light.hide(); 
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".ui-lightbox-content-wrapper", "click", function (event) {
    light.hide(); 
});
```

if your lightBox got an id you can use `....delegate("#idOfLightBox ",....`

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. This didn't work for me, but you led me in the right direction. Since the html-content is added on runtime, i choose the onShow-callback of p:lightbox. `<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox" widgetVar="light" onShow="jQuery(document).on('click', '.ui-lightbox-content-wrapper', function (event) {light.hide()});"> ...`. **ui-lightbox-content-wrapper** is the class of the generated div, in which the lightbox is.

Comment: You are welcome , I looked at the first primefaces showcase example that's why took that class as an anchor... (The Important part is the Idea behind...)